# JSON Object contents "old" values

Tags: android, json, variables, path

My broadcast receiver submits the path in a variable via "newIntent.putExtra". The path is displayed correctly in the activity called by the receiver in a TextView, but when I use the variable for creating a JSONObject, the value which it was initialized with is used instead. The server I try to upload to requests a JSON-String for authorisation.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    new Loader().execute();

    TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewPath)   
    tv4.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString(BroadcastReceiver.EXTRA_PATH));
    }

class Loader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>{
ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //different SDK-Versions
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadToServer.this, ProgressDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT);
        }
    else {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadToServer.this);
        }

    dialog.setMessage(Html.fromHtml("<b>"+"Loading..."+"</b>"));
    dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();
    }

@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return postJsonObject("Put your url which takes json object", makingJson());
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result!=null) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "Successfully posted json object", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    public JSONObject makingJson() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("username", API_USER);
            jsonObject.put("password", API_PASS);
            jsonObject.put("name", name);
            jsonObject.put("apk_file_location", BroadcastReceiver.EXTRA_PATH);
            } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return jsonObject;
    }

    public JSONObject postJsonObject(String urlServer, JSONObject jsonObject){

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";
        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Create HttpClient
            URI url = new URI(URLEncoder.encode(urlServer, "UTF-8"));
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            String json = "";
            json = jsonObject.toString();
            System.out.println(json);
            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this, "json object: "+json, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json)
            httpPost.setEntity(se);  // Set httpPost Entity  
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            if(inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "postJsonObject did not work!";
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
....
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same valid path as shown on your textview, try to put your `TextView tv4` as global variable then use the `tv4.getText().toString()` to pass the value to your `makingJson()` function

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I could not define the TextView as a global variable, but I found a workaround:

Answer (score 0):

Since the path was displayed correctly in the TextView I finally put the content of it into another variable:

```
public JSONObject makingJson() {
        final TextView textViewPath = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewPath);
        String path = textViewPath.getText().toString
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("username", API_USER);
            jsonObject.put("password", API_PASS);
            jsonObject.put("name", name);
            jsonObject.put("file_location", path);
        ....
```

Maybe it is not the most elegant way, but it worked.